# How do I return after JS promises are resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do the following.

```
import axios from 'axios';
function testURL(url) {
  var data = axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/api/test`, { url } )
      .then(res => {
        return res.data;
      })
  return data
}
```

It's to be used in React JSX, something like `{testURL(props.url)}`. The issue I'm having is that it returns a promise, when really what I need it to do is return the response.

I'm not sure exactly where to put the return statements to get what I'm after. Do I need to make it blocking somehow?

Comment: Your only real option is to use the Promise as-is, you can't parse data retrieved asynchronously in a synchronous manner

Comment: What would you propose then? Use something other then axios that doesn't support promises?

Comment: You should just use the Promise - call `.then` on the call of `testURL`

Comment: The difficult is when I do this, it seems to try to render the promise first, resulting in:
`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: There are [many results](https://www.google.com/search?q="Objects+are+not+valid+as+a+React+child+(found%3A+[object+Promise])"), check them out - if not enough, ask a question about how to fix your React code (there's nothing wrong with your use of promises here)